# Register username and password

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, tkinter, textbox

My save and read function not working properly. Does i save the data in text file correctly?And does i read the data in text file correctly? Can somebody correct me if the save and read in text file not correct.Others code i think works as well.

```
import Tkinter 
WindowBox = Tkinter.Tk()
WindowBox.geometry("250x200")
WindowBox.title("Welcome to E-UPSR")

getusername1 = Tkinter.StringVar()
getpassword1 = Tkinter.StringVar()
getusername2 = Tkinter.StringVar()
getpassword2 = Tkinter.StringVar()

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Username:")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox, textvariable= getusername1)
TxtBoxName.pack()

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Password:")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox, textvariable= getpassword1)
TxtBoxName.pack()

student=[]


def read():
    if len(getusername1.get()) or len(getpassword1.get())==0:
            labelShowName=Tkinter.Label(WindowBox, text="Invalid").pack()
    else:
        addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
        addstudent.read("Username:" + getusername1.get())
        addstudent.read("Password: " + getpassword1.get())
        addstudent.close ()
        WindowBox.withdraw()
        MenuBox.deiconify()   
    return

def register():
    WindowBox.withdraw()
    RegBox.deiconify()
    return

RegBox = Tkinter.Tk()
RegBox.geometry("250x200")
RegBox.title("register")

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Username:")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox, textvariable= getusername2)
TxtBoxName.pack()
LabelName = Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Password:")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox, textvariable= getpassword2)
TxtBoxName.pack()
RegBox.withdraw()

def back():
    RegBox.withdraw()
    WindowBox.deiconify()
    return    


def save():
    while True:
        if len(getusername2.get())== 0 or len(getpassword2.get())== 0:
            labelShowName=Tkinter.Label(RegBox, text="Please key-in").pack()
            break
        else:
            addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
            addstudent.write('Username:' + getusername2.get())
            addstudent.write('Password:' + getpassword2.get())
            labelShowName=Tkinter.Label(RegBox, text="Done").pack()
            return
    len(getusername2.get() and getpassword2.get())!= 0
    return

MenuBox = Tkinter.Tk()
MenuBox.geometry("250x200")
MenuBox.title("MainMenu")
MenuBox.withdraw()

BtnName = Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Back", command=back).pack()   
BtnName = Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Enter", command=save).pack()
BtnName = Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Register", command=register).pack()
BtnName = Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Proceed", command=read).pack()
```

Comment: @WoLy tq very much i appreciate so much of your work. Can you be my teacher haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `open ("student.txt", "w")` the `student.txt` file will be ecrased each time you call save method.
You need to append, use:

```
open("student.txt", "a")
```

You are using two `Tk` windows, it's better to use `TopLevel` windows for that.

In `read()` method, to test for password and username use:

```
def read():
   if not getusername1.get() or not getpassword1.get():
       #Your code
```

In `save()` method, you do not need `while True`:

```
def save():
    if not getusername2.get() or not getpassword2.get():
        #Show an error massage
    else:
        #Save the file
```

To show an error message you can use `tkmassagebox.showerror()`:

```
import tkMessageBox
.
.
.
tkMessageBox.showerror('Invalid', 'Empty username or password')
```

In both `read()` and `save()` methods you wrote :

```
labelShowName=Tkinter.Label(WindowBox, text="Invalid").pack()
```

`labelShowName` variable will be `None` because `pack()` method does not return anything, to keep reference to the `Label` you can use:

```
labelShowName=Tkinter.Label(WindowBox, text="Invalid")
labelShowName.pack()
```

The same thing for all line like:

```
BtnName = Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Back", command=back).pack()
```

Use instead:

```
BtnName = Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Back", command=back)
BtnName.pack()
```

If you do not need to keep a reference to the button use:

```
Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Back", command=back).pack()
```

You are using the same variable name with differente `Tkinter.Entry()` widgets, you shoud get confused with that.

**EDIT:**

```
import Tkinter 
import tkMessageBox
WindowBox = Tkinter.Tk()
WindowBox.geometry("250x200")
WindowBox.title("Welcome to E-UPSR")


Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Username:").pack()

username1 = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox)
username1.pack()

Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Password:").pack()

password1 = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox)
password1.pack()

student=[]


def read():
    if not username1.get() or not password1.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('Invalid', 'Empty username or password')
    else:
        addstudent = open ("student.txt", "r")
        lines = addstudent.readlines()
        addstudent.close ()
        i = 0
        while i < len(lines) - 1:
            # username and password are saved in two line, label and value are separated by ':'.
            # to get them we need to reed two line in each iteration and split with ':' to get the value (second result of spliting) then strip to remove end line.
            user = lines[i].split(':')[1].strip()
            password = lines[i+1].split(':')[1].strip()
            # test if the user is registred 
            if user == username1.get() and  password == password1.get():
                WindowBox.withdraw()
                MenuBox.deiconify()
                break
            i += 2  
    return

def register():
    WindowBox.withdraw()
    RegBox.deiconify()
    return

RegBox = Tkinter.Tk()
RegBox.geometry("250x200")
RegBox.title("register")

Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Username:").pack()

username2 = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox)
username2.pack()

Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Password:").pack()
password2 = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox)
password2.pack()
RegBox.withdraw()

def back():
    RegBox.withdraw()
    WindowBox.deiconify()
    return    


def save():
    if not username2.get() or not password2.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('Invalid', 'Empty username or password')
    else:
        addstudent = open ("student.txt", "a")
        addstudent.write('Username:' + username2.get() + '\n')
        addstudent.write('Password:' + password2.get()+'\n')
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Writing", "Done")
    return

MenuBox = Tkinter.Tk()
MenuBox.geometry("250x200")
MenuBox.title("MainMenu")
MenuBox.withdraw()

Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Back", command=back).pack()   
Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Enter", command=save).pack()
Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Register", command=register).pack()
Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Proceed", command=read).pack()


WindowBox.mainloop()
```

I did not use `Tkinter.StringVar()`.

Comment: what happen if the text box is empty?

Comment: thnks it works, I forget to import tkmassagebox. But still my save()function not works.

Comment: i already key in the username and password but still the tkmassagebox error appear.

Comment: tkmassagebox error will be shown if username or password is empty.

Comment: i already key in the username and password but still the tkmassagebox appear. I look in the student text file also empty

Comment: @student Please edit your code to show your changes.

Comment: read() method? Isnt it calling back the save file when register?

Comment: when user click button proceed read() will read the text file if it match then menubox will deiconify

Comment: i just dont know if the method im using is correct i just found in the internet  it use this method. How to match up the save() the username and password and read() username and password so that it can proceed to the menuboxv

Comment: @student Check my edit.Please delete your answer do edit on your question.